# Unable to verify Forge callback payload signature

Tags: c#, autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge, autodesk-webhooks

I am currently using Forge Webhooks API to handle different events that might occur on a project. Everything works fine, except the payload signature check.

The reason why I want to check the payload is because the callback will end up on my API and I want to reject all requests that do not come from Forge's webhook service.

---

Steps I followed:

1. Add (register) secret key (token) on Forge. [API Reference](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/tokens-POST/)
2. Trigger an event that will eventually call my API for handling it.
3. Validating signature header. Followed [this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/tutorials/how-to-verify-payload-signature/).
4. PROBLEM!!! My `computedSignature` is different from the signature received from Forge.

---

My C# code looks like this:

`private const string SHA_HASH = "sha1hash";`

```
var secretKeyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ForgeAuthConfiguration.AntiForgeryToken);

using var hmac = new HMACSHA1(secretKeyBytes);

var computedHash = hmac.ComputeHash(request.Body.ReadAsBytes());

var computedSignature = $"{SHA_HASH}={computedHash.Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + $"{e:x2}", s => s)}";
```

---

For one example, Forge's request has this signature header: `sha1hash=303c4e7d2a94ccfa559560dc2421cee8496d2d83`

My C# code computes this signature: `sha1hash=3bb8d41c3c1cb6c9652745f5996b4e7f832ca8d5`

*The same AntiForgeryToken was sent to Forge at step 1*

Ok, I thought my C# code is broken, then I tried [this online HMAC generator](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html#ad-output) and for the given input, result is: `3bb8d41c3c1cb6c9652745f5996b4e7f832ca8d5` *(same as C#)*

Ok, maybe the online generator is broken, I tried their own code in node js and this is the result:

[image]

---

I have 3 ways of encrypting the SAME body using the SAME key and I get the SAME result every time. BUT those results are DIFFERENT from the signature provided by Forge, resulting in failing the check and rejecting a valid request...

**Does anyone know what is happening with that signature?**

**Why is it different from my result if I follow their tutorial?**

**How are you validating your requests?**

Comment: Was this ever resolved?

Answer (score 1):

The code below is working at my side. Could you give it a try if it helps?

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/forge/callback/webhookbysig")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> WebhookCallbackBySig()
    {
        try
        {
            var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            byte[] rawBody = null;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                rawBody = encoding.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
            }
            var requestSignature = Request.Headers["x-adsk-signature"];
            string myPrivateToken = Credentials.GetAppSetting("FORGE_WEBHOOK_PRIVATE_TOKEN");
            var tokenBytes = encoding.GetBytes(myPrivateToken);
            var hmacSha1 = new HMACSHA1(tokenBytes);
            byte[] hashmessage = hmacSha1.ComputeHash(rawBody);
            var calculatedSignature = "sha1hash=" + BitConverter.ToString(hashmessage).ToLower().Replace("-", "");
            if (requestSignature.Equals(calculatedSignature))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Same!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("diff!");
            }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

        // ALWAYS return ok (200)

        return Ok();        
 }
```

If this does not help, please share with your webhook ID (better send email at forge.help@autodesk.com). We will ask engineer team to check it.

Comment: Still not working. I am starting to assume that either the TOKEN is different either the body (removed new lines, spaces, any small change). Also the body I receive has some weird characters: `"dm_attr_v1:1195270": "ðð"`. I will send them an email, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The way to check the signature is correct, I believe the issue is setting the secret token, did you correctly set the secret token for your App by endpoint https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/http/tokens/tokens-POST/ ? Make sure to use the secret token to verify all the coming callback.